# Passing Match to Private Route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have some code for private routes that require authentication. I cannot figure out why Match is not being passed down to the child component. In the child component through Private Route, Match is coming up as `undefined`

Match is accessible as expected in the child components for the regular `Route`, but not for the `PrivateRoute`.

Routes.js

```
const Routes = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
      <Route exact path="/password/:id?" component={Password} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/c/new" component={NewComp} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/c/:id/manage" component={ManageComp} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

PrivateRoute.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import Spinner from "../components/Common/Layout/Spinner";

const PrivateRoute = props => {
  const {
    component: Component,
    auth: { isAuthenticated, loading },
    ...rest
  } = props;

  if (loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }
  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Redirect
        to={{
          pathname: "/login",
          state: {
            alert: "login",
            redir: window.location.pathname + window.location.search
          }
        }}
      />
    );
  }
  return <Component {...props} />;
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

ManageComp.js

```js
const ManageComp = ({
  loadComp,
  competition: { competition, loading },
  match
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(match); /*CONSOLE SHOWS MATCH AS UNDEFINED*/
    loadComp();
  }, []);

  return loading ? <Spinner /> : <div>PAGE HTML</div>;
};

ManageComp.propTypes = {
  loadComp: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  competition: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  competition: state.competition
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { loadComp }
)(ManageComp);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your PrivateRoute.js i think you need to return Route

```
  return (
          <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
            <Component {...props} />
          )}/>
        )
```

this is example of my PrivateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuthenticated = stores.auth.isAuthenticated
  if(isAuthenticated){
            return (
              <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
                <Component {...props} />
              )}/>
            )
  }

  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={(props) => (
      <Redirect to='/Login'/>
    )}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Success! Thank you!